# Why can't could be used in this sentence?

Tags: modal-verbs

> ✲ I left early and could get a seat.
>   (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language)

CGEL says “*could* does not normally appear in affirmative contexts when it is a matter of actualisaiton of a single situation viewed perfectively*.” But as I’m not an English user, not finding any semantic strangeness from the example. Can you explain why *could* can’t be used in the example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Could* is no longer used as the simple past of *can* in contexts like these, because the tentative or counterfactual use of *could* is now the “default” reading and using it in a factual sense would confuse the reader.

This is another reason why non-modal verb phrases like *be able to* and *be going to* and *be willing to* are replacing full modals; these don't have the ‘dual’ use of their past forms, so it is less ambiguous to say

> I left early and **was able to** get a seat.

Note that this sentence is entirely acceptable:

> I left early **so** I could get a seat.

There the *could* is non-factual—it is equivalent to *would be able to* or *might be able to*.